# Load Javascript dynamically with 2 different methods

Tags: javascript, load

After spend hours trying to find the best method to import a dynamically JS I came to 2 alternatives. The first one is used by Analytics and many famous JS libraries but the second method is a little smaller and easier to understand, why is it not used by Google Analytics or other major JS libraries?

1)

```
a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="http://sitepor500.com.br/scripts.js?1";c=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c);
```

2)

```
a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="http://sitepor500.com.br/scripts.js?2";document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(a);
```

I understand that these 2 methods look almost the same but the first one inserts the script before the first  tag in the page and the second method inserts the script as the last nested brother of the first  in the page.

As the second method is smaller, easier to understand, why is it not used? Does it have a problem with some particular browser version or brand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with browsers, it is all about:

```
c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c);
```

and

```
c.parentNode.appendChild(a);
```

the first one is trying to inject a script, before all the other script tags in the page.this part:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
```

gets the first script tag in the page, then injects the script tag right before that. **Whay is that?**, because, the first solution wants to add a script to page and make sure it is the first to execute. but the second solution just want to append a script to page, if you use other libraries like `jQuery`, `bootstarp` or whatever, and you have used them in your script, you should use the second solution, because as I said you won't have access to any of other scripts in your page if you use the first solution.

**BUT** if you change the first method like this:

```
//...
var scripts=document.body.querySelectorAll("script:last-child");
c=scripts[scripts.length];
```

now c here is the last script tag in your page, and if you use insertBefore to append your script tag:

```
c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c);
```

it gets inserted before the first script tag in the c DOM level. and it gets executed before the other scripts in the same DOM level. So `insertBefore` doesn't have anything to do with being the first script tag to be executed and if it is so for your first method, the reason is you are selecting the first script tag in the whole DOM with:

```
c=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
```

and inserting your script tag right before that:

```
c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c);
```

Comment: Thanks and you are right! But I have another question: if I have a page with <head> and many scripts being imported in it, and after that I have a <body> with also many script being imported in it, and at the end of the <body> I insert the method 1. In this case will the script, that is being imported at the end of the body tag, be imported before all other scripts in the page even if it is being imported at the end of the body? Will the browsers first read the HTML code looking to "insertBefore" to make sure the scripts are imported in the right order? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3262028: I changed my answer to address your questions, I really tried to clarify it.

Comment: I took a while to understand what you said but it's dam right! I did some test in Chrome and FF and it worked as you said. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First method

```
parentNode.insertBefore(a,c);
```

ensures that it will append a DOM object {here : **a**} at the beginning of specified DOM Object {here : **c**}. While

```
parentNode.appendChild(a);
```

ensures that it will append any DOM object at the end of specified place DOM Object.

So first method ensures that appended scripts will get executed first. For eg : consider a case when subsequent scripts require {here : **a**} to execute properly.

Comment: I tried to make a test and make sure your are right but my test proves otherwise. Look: create an HTML file and copy/paste both methods inside <body> but make the second method come first. Change the src of method 2 to "test2.php" and the src of method 1 to "test1.php". The content of test2.php must be "console.log('appendChild');" and test1.php must be "console.log('insertBefore');". If you run this code you will see that the console will log first "appendChild" and after "insertBefore" which proves that something went wrong and is not according to what you said! Thank you so much for helping